# Remove all ul within li except the current li

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to remove all `ul` within `li` except the current `li`.

```
<ul>
        <li id="Li0">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Childnode1</span></li></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="Li1">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Childnode2</span></li></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="Li2">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Childnode3</span></li></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="Li3">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Childnode4</span></li></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="Li4">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Childnode5</span></li></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="Li5">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Childnode6</span></li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

So If i click on the `li` with id 'li4' every other `li` that are previous to this `li` or next to this `li` should have there `ul` to be removed from dom.

I was thinking of using the `.not` operator in jquery but till now not able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wwvBL/

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    var obj= $(this);
    id= obj.attr('id');
    obj.parent().find('li:not(#'+id+') > ul').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

is that what you are searching for?

```
  $(function(){
            $('li').click(function(){
                $(this).siblings().children("ul").remove();
            });        
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
$(function () {
    $('ul:first').delegate("li[id^='L']", 'click', function () {
        $("ul:first > li[id!='"+$(this).attr('id')+"'] > ul").remove();
    });        
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EJWnn/

Answer (score 0):

Use siblings to find all other adjacent elements:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().find("ul").remove();
});
```

You might want to have a more specific selector than "li".